# SQL generate series by week return 0 if nothing found

Tags: sql, postgresql

When no data is found for a week, the SQL will return 1. How can I make it return 0?

```
SELECT w.week, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             max(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             interval '7 day'
                            ) as week
      FROM reviews
     ) w LEFT JOIN
     "reviews" 
     ON DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) = w.week
GROUP BY w.week
ORDER BY w.week;
```

Comment: you have outer join, so `count(*)` to `count(reviews.*)` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have outer join, so changing `count(*)` to `count(reviews.*)` should do, try:

```
SELECT w.week, COUNT(reviews.*) AS total
FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             max(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             interval '7 day'
                            ) as week
      FROM reviews
     ) w LEFT JOIN
     "reviews" 
     ON DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) = w.week
GROUP BY w.week
ORDER BY w.week;
```